# Gerar imagens para PDF utilizando PDFSharp -Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, imagem, pdf

Estou utilizando window form .net e gostaria de converter imagens escaneadas para PDF gerando assim páfinas  de imagens no PDF. Estou utilizando o PDFSharp.
Tenho o seguinte código mas ele só gera uma página.Quais comandos devo utilizar para gerar pegar as imagens e gerar o PDF com paginas.
à princípio penso em  carregar uma DataTable e após isso ler cada uma das linhas e gerar mas não sei como fazer....Poderiam me dar uma dica?

```
    private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string source = (e.Argument as string[])[0];
            string destinaton = (e.Argument as string[])[1];

            PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
            doc.Pages.Add(new PdfPage());
            XGraphics xgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(doc.Pages[0]);


            XImage img = XImage.FromFile(source);
            doc.Pages[0].Width = XUnit.FromPoint(img.Size.Width);
            doc.Pages[0].Height = XUnit.FromPoint(img.Size.Height);
            xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, img.Size.Width, img.Size.Height); 
            doc.Save(destinaton);
            doc.Close();
            success = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No seguinte trecho, você adicionou a primeira página[1]:

```
    doc.Pages.Add(new PdfPage());
```

E adicionou uma imagem à primeira página(*index* = 0, indicado com o código doc.pages[0]) do seu *PdfDocument*[2]:

```
    XGraphics xgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(doc.Pages[0]);    
    xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, img.Size.Width, img.Size.Height);
```

Para criar mais páginas, você só precisar instanciar uma nova página[1] e adicionar a cada nova página o contéudo desejado[2].